# If $a + b$ and $ab$ are algebraic, then $a$ and $b$ are also algebraic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field with characteristic different from $2$. Let $E$ be its extension and let $a, b \in E$. Prove: If $a + b$ and $ab$ are algebraic, then $a$ and $b$ are also algebraic.

Attempt: Assume that $a + b$ and $ab$ are algebraic.
This means that there exist polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ with coefficients from field F such that $f(a + b) = 0$ and $g(ab) = 0$.
We can express polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ as $f(x) = c_nx^n + c_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + c_1x + c_0$ and $g(x) = d_mx^m + d_{m-1}x^{m-1} + \ldots + d_1x + d_0$, where $c_i$ and $d_i$ are coefficients from field $F$, and $n$ and $m$ are the degrees of polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, respectively.
Since $a + b$ is a zero of polynomial $f(x)$, we have $f(a + b) = c_n(a+b)^n + c_{n-1}(a+b)^{n-1} + \ldots + c_1(a + b) + c_0 = 0$.
Similarly, since ab is a zero of polynomial $g(x)$, we have $g(ab) = d_ma^m b^m + d_{m-1}a^{m-1} b^{m-1} + \ldots + d_1ab + d_0 = 0$, but I don't know how to continue. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Here is a [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial for your mathematical expressions.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2055374/transitivity-of-algebraic-field-extensions

Comment: They are roots of a quadratic polynomial with algebraic coefficients

Answer (score 2):

If $a+b$ and $ab$ are both algebraic, then so is $(a+b)^2-4ab=a^2-2ab+b^2=(a-b)^2$.  But if $(a-b)^2$ is algebraic, then $a-b$ also is algebraic, and if $a+b$ and $a-b$ both are algebraic, so are $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Simpler: $a,b$ are roots of $\,x^2-(a+b)x+ab$ with algebraic coef's (no need to explicitly show how to solve a quadratic).

Answer (score 1):

Let $K=F(a+b)=F[a+b]$. As $a+b$ is algebraic over $F$, the extension $K:F$ is finite.
Let $L=K(ab)=K[ab]$. As $ab$ is algebraic over $F$, it is also algebraic over $K$ so the extension $L:K$ is finite.

Thus, *the extension $L:F$ is finite* (and, as you know, $[L:F]=[L:K][K:F]$)

Now, solve the quadratic equation $(x-a)(x-b)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab=0$ with coefficients in $L$. The solutions are: $\frac{(a+b)\pm\sqrt{D}}{2}$ where $D=(a+b)^2-4ab\in L$ and $\pm\sqrt{D}$ are algebraic over $L$, being roots of the quadratic equation $x^2-D=0$. Note where we are using the fact that the characteristic of $F$ is not $2$: we have $2:=1+1\ne 0$ so we can divide with it in the quadratic formula.

Now, say, $M=L(\sqrt{D})=L[\sqrt{D}]$. By the same argument as above, we conclude that $M$ is a finite extension of $L$, therefore a finite extension of $F$.

However, $a, b\in M$ so $F(a), F(b)\subseteq M$ and the extensions $F(a):F$ and $F(b):F$ are both finite. Thus, $a, b$ are both algebraic.